# php - mutlplying values from one array with values in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with two databases.  One database is on Microsoft SQL 2012 and the other is on MySQL 5.5. Microsoft SQL Server has an Orders table and the MySQL has three Currency Exchange Rate tables.  The Orders table has orders from 6 different countries; however, orders from 3 of the countries have sales totals in their local currencies (non-U.S.).  The 3 Currency Exchange Rates tables are separated by country containing daily rates.  Using PHP, I need to get current years total sales grouped by month and country and have the exchange rates applied to those countries total sales that are not in U.S. currency.  Each months exchange rate needs to be the average rate for that month.

I have two arrays below.  The first array is for the orders which have the sales summed and grouped by month and country.  The second array is for the currency exchange rate which has the average exchange rates calculated and grouped by month and country.

How would I multiply the total sales each month by the exchange rate for the countries that are not in U.S. currency, which are KR, JP, and NZ?

### Orders

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT MONTH(US_OrderDate) AS MONTH, a.Country, SUM(a.Sales) AS Total_Sales FROM (
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN Country = 'KR' THEN DATEADD(DAY, +1, CAST(OrderDate AS Date)) 
        ELSE CAST(OrderDate as Date) END AS US_OrderDate, Country, SUM(Total) AS Sales FROM Orders 
WHERE (OrderStatusID in ('7','8','9') AND Country = 'KR')
OR (OrderStatusID in ('7','8','9') AND Country = 'JP')
OR (OrderStatusID in ('7','8','9') AND Country = 'AU')
OR (OrderStatusID in ('7','8','9') AND Country = 'NZ')
OR (OrderStatusID in ('7','8','9') AND Country = 'US')
OR (OrderStatusID in ('7','8','9') AND Country = 'CA')
GROUP BY CAST(OrderDate as Date),Country) AS a
WHERE YEAR(US_OrderDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(US_OrderDate), a.Country
Order BY MONTH(US_OrderDate) ASC
");
try {
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("{error: {$e->getMessage()}}");
}



array(54) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "AU"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(7) "9095.70"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "113993.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "KR"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(7) "9284.75"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(6) "883.25"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "609538.25"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "AU"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(7) "7393.65"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "100279.43"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "JP"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "916110.00"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "KR"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(7) "5217.55"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(7) "1355.85"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "616422.11"
  }
  ....
```

### Exchange Rates

```
$query_exchange_rate = $db_exchange_rate->prepare("SELECT Month(date) AS MONTH, 'NZ' AS Country, ROUND((SUM(rate)/COUNT(rate)),5) AS AVG_RATE FROM currency_exchange_rates.new_zealand WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY MONTH(date)
    UNION
SELECT Month(date) AS MONTH, 'JP' AS Country, ROUND((SUM(rate)/COUNT(rate)),5) AS AVG_RATE FROM currency_exchange_rates.japan WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY MONTH(date)
    UNION
SELECT Month(date) AS MONTH, 'KR' AS Country, ROUND((SUM(rate)/COUNT(rate)),5) AS AVG_RATE FROM currency_exchange_rates.south_korea WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY MONTH(date)
ORDER BY MONTH ASC");

try {
    $query_exchange_rate->execute();
    $results_exchange_rate = $query_exchange_rate->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("{error: {$e->getMessage()}}");
}


array(27) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["AVG_RATE"]=>
    string(7) "0.76614"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "JP"
    ["AVG_RATE"]=>
    string(7) "0.00845"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "KR"
    ["AVG_RATE"]=>
    string(7) "0.00090"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "NZ"
    ["AVG_RATE"]=>
    string(7) "0.74309"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "JP"
    ["AVG_RATE"]=>
    string(7) "0.00842"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "KR"
    ["AVG_RATE"]=>
    string(7) "0.00090"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through them. A simplistic way is to loop through the long one, looping through the short one each time.

```
foreach($results as &$a) // Need to be by reference to update it easily
  foreach($results_exchange_rate as $b)
    if($a['MONTH'] == $b['MONTH'] && $a['Country']==$b['Country'])
      $a['Total_Sales']*= $b['AVG_RATE'];
```

That will multiply Total Sales by Avg Rate every time Month and Country are the same in both arrays.